# How count of numbers id for a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am looking for a way to count the number of id in a period of time every 30 minutes.

I wrote a SQL query, but the result is incorrect

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#tabl]
(
    [Id] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [TIMEStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [TIMEEnd] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tabl] VALUES ('1', '2020-04-01 00:05:00.000', '2020-04-01 00:10:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tabl] VALUES ('2', '2020-04-01 00:11:00.000', '2020-04-01 00:29:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tabl] VALUES ('3', '2020-04-01 00:12:00.000', '2020-04-01 00:55:00.000')

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        [Id], 
        DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [TIMEStart], [TIMEEnd]) / 30) * 30, 0) AS RangeTime
    FROM
        [dbo].[#tabl]
    GROUP BY
        [Id], DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [TIMEStart],[TIMEEnd]) / 30) * 30, 0)
)
SELECT numreq, RangeTime
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS numreq, RangeTime
     FROM CTE
     GROUP BY RangeTime) temp
```

Correct result - table:

```
numreq       RangeTime
-------------------------------------
3            1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 
1            1900-01-01 00:30:00.000
```

Period of time:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 - includes 3 id:1, 2, 3
1900-01-01 00:30:00.000 - includes 1 id:1
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? Are you expecting a output that may have 0 events in a 30 minute period? Or are you asking simply how to "round a time to the nearest 30 minute"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is to create a list of `RangeTime` values that lie within the range of the `TIMEStart` and `TIMEEnd` values in `tabl` (which you can do with a recursive CTE), then you can `JOIN` that list back to `tabl` on an overlapping time range and count the number of rows that overlap each `RangeTime`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MIN([TIMEStart]))/30)*30,0) as RangeTime, 
         MAX([TIMEEnd]) AS MaxTime
  FROM [dbo].[tabl]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, RangeTime), MaxTime
  FROM CTE
  WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, RangeTime) < MaxTime
)
SELECT RangeTime, COUNT(tabl.Id) AS numreq 
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN tabl ON tabl.TIMEStart < DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, RangeTime)
              AND RangeTime <= tabl.TIMEEnd
GROUP BY RangeTime
```

Output:

```
RangeTime               numreq
2020-04-01T00:00:00Z    3
2020-04-01T00:30:00Z    1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9fbe3/14)

Note: I've presumed you want the actual time for the range, not times starting at the beginning of 1900...